# Getting network information with ChromeDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I'm trying to access the network tab information from a chrome page that was launched with ChromeDriver in C#.

[image]

I would like total data transferred and page load time at the least...

I've been messing around with setting different `ChromeOptions` and `DesiredCapabilities`, much to no success. The only thing I've gotten to work so far is executing a script and converting the results to a long.

`Convert.ToInt64(((IJavaScriptExecutor)ChromeDriver).ExecuteScript("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart"));`

however, I'd like to not do it this way, if that's possible... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In that case that other people are seeing this in the future I will share some information. Because I have currently also have problems with devtools.

There is an [official guide](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/chrome_devtools/) from Selenium if you are using an 4.0 alpha how to interact with dev tools.

I will share the snipet here I'm currently using.

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
session.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
session.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());
```

```
public void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine($"Status: { e.Response.Status } : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: 
   { e.Response.MimeType } | Url: { e.Response.Url } ");
}
```

I tried a lot to figure out how I can get the information I want to.
Maybe my [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69461981/13163366) is answered until you see this, I shared everything I have tried out.

Also [this guide](https://dotjord.wordpress.com/2020/09/13/how-to-capture-network-activity-with-selenium-4-in-asp-net-core-3-1/) can help you to get started.

Comment: This code is from the beta, here's the same method WORKING in the alpha: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71671844/495455