# There are no "CreateDevToolsSession" in ChromeDriver Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium and trying to use CDP to mock Geolocation. But I'm having a problem that the ChromeDriver dont have anything like CreateDevToolsSession.
This is the code that I've found in the Selenium Documentation:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V87.Emulation;

namespace dotnet_test {
  class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      GeoLocation().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static async Task GeoLocation() {
      ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      DevToolsSession devToolsSession = driver.CreateDevToolsSession();
      var geoLocationOverrideCommandSettings = new SetGeolocationOverrideCommandSettings();

      geoLocationOverrideCommandSettings.Latitude = 51.507351;
      geoLocationOverrideCommandSettings.Longitude = -0.127758;
      geoLocationOverrideCommandSettings.Accuracy = 1;

      await devToolsSession
        .GetVersionSpecificDomains<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V87.DevToolsSessionDomains>()
        .Emulation
        .SetGeolocationOverride(geoLocationOverrideCommandSettings);

        driver.Url = "<your site url>";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

** UPDATE 1 **
This is the link for the documentation references.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/

Comment: Can you update the link to the documentation for reference please?

Comment: Here bro. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/

Comment: Please update the main question with thiis link for better visibility.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot. Im new :D. But do you know anyway to fix this :(

Comment: Let me have a look at the docs once.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Selenium 4 Breaking Changes**

`CreateDevToolsSession()` has been replaced with `GetDevToolsSession()`.

A lot of examples you find online were written with the Beta version, like this one: https://dotjord.wordpress.com/2020/09/13/how-to-capture-network-activity-with-selenium-4-in-asp-net-core-3-1/ and this old code gets copied around https://stackoverflow.com/a/69478097/495455

Beta (old code):

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
session.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
session.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
public void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Status: { e.Response.Status } : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: { e.Response.MimeType } | Url: { e.Response.Url }");
}
```

Alpha (working code):

```
using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.DevToolsSessionDomains;
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
var devTools = (IDevTools)driver;
IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
domains.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
await domains.Network.Enable(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.Network.EnableCommandSettings());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Status: { e.Response.Status } : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: { e.Response.MimeType } | Url: { e.Response.Url }");
}
```

Comment: this code does not work. problem with 
            using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.DevToolsSessionDomains;

Answer (score 2):

In a addition to the nice answer from [Jeremy Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson), I wanted to share a new approach without being version and browser specific for Selenium 4+. (Works in Chrome and Edge with Selenium 4.8)

```
public void SetupNetworkLogging(IWebDriver driver)
{
    NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager(driver);
    manager.NetworkResponseReceived += ResponseHandler;
    manager.StartMonitoring();
}

private void ResponseHandler(object sender, NetworkResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Http status: {e.ResponseStatusCode} : {e.ResponseBody} | Url: {e.ResponseUrl} ");
}
```

The [official documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/#emulate-geo-location) for geolocation is now updated, for geolocation it seems to be nessessary, but if you don't need to specify a version use that:

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
var session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/).